# How can I set default build target for Cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I tried to make 'Hello World' in Rust using [this tutorial](https://rustwasm.github.io/book/game-of-life/hello-world.html), but the build command is a bit verbose:

```
cargo +nightly build --target wasm32-unknown-unknown --release
```

Is it possible to set the default target for `cargo build`?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You could use a [Cargo configuration file](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html) to specify a default target-triple for your project. In your project's root, create a `.cargo` directory and a `config.toml` file in it with the following contents:

```ini
[build]
target = "wasm32-unknown-unknown"
```

Comment: Is it work expectedly too now? I got the warning:
`warning: unused manifest key: build`
using 1.47.0-nightly.

Comment: Are you putting it in `Cargo.toml`?. You need to use `.cargo/config`

Comment: Additional note: while you absolutely can call the file `config`, you can also call it `config.toml`. It will behave excactly the same, but your editor might now improve syntax highlighting and whatnot.

Comment: @ZacharyPerkins: From what I know the `config.toml` filename with extension included is not supported for older versions of Cargo (released before ~2020). For current versions it is the preferred name, though.

Answer (score 22):

As listed in [the Cargo documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html), you can create a `.cargo/config` and specify the target:

```
[build]
target = "my-custom-target"
```

Comment: Thank you! And for others reading this in the future, you can see what targets Rust supports using `rustc --print target-list`.

Comment: @C.Dunn And if using rustup, you can do `rustup target list` as well.

Answer (score 5):

If you're able to use unstable features, following [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/unstable.html#unstable-features) and especially [`per-package-target` feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/unstable.html#per-package-target) add this to you crate manifest that usually named Cargo.toml

```ini
cargo-features = ["per-package-target"]

[package]
forced-target = "wasm32-unknown-unknown"
# and/or:
default-target = "wasm32-unknown-unknown"
```

This requires nightly toolchain.