# Why is the TARGET environment variable reset when compiling a Rust program in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, rust

I'm trying to cross-compile a Rust binary with Docker for raspberry-pi on ARM6 architecture. I'm specifying the environment arguments for Cargo prior to building, but it errors out on a specific library saying that the "-m64" argument was not found.

The environment arguments when the error happens are different than what I set up in the Dockerfile; why are they being reset?

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install \
    --yes \
    binutils \
    build-essential \
    curl \
    git \
    wget \
    libudev-dev \
    zip

ARG RASPBERRY_PI_TOOLS_COMMIT_ID=5caa7046982f0539cf5380f94da04b31129ed521
ENV CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
ENV TARGET=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
ENV CARGO_CFG_TARGET_ARCH=arm
ENV CARGO_CFG_TARGET_ENDIAN=little
ENV CARGO_CFG_TARGET_ENV=gnu
ENV CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FAMILY=unix
ENV CARGO_CFG_TARGET_OS=linux
ENV CARGO_CFG_TARGET_POINTER_WIDTH=32
ENV CARGO_FEATURE_DEFAULT=1
ENV CARGO_FEATURE_DEV_URANDOM_FALLBACK=1
ENV CARGO_FEATURE_RSA_SIGNING=1
ENV CARGO_FEATURE_USE_HEAP=1
ENV LD=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/src/parity/target/release/deps:/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib:/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib
ENV QEMU_LD_PREFIX=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc
RUN wget https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/archive/$RASPBERRY_PI_TOOLS_COMMIT_ID.zip -O /root/pi-tools.zip
RUN unzip /root/pi-tools.zip -d /root
RUN mv /root/tools-$RASPBERRY_PI_TOOLS_COMMIT_ID /root/pi-tools
ENV PATH=/root/pi-tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin:$PATH
ENV PATH=/root/pi-tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3:$PATH

# Install Rust.
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y --verbose
ENV PATH=/root/.cargo/bin:$PATH

# Install the arm target for Rust.
RUN rustup target add arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
# Configure the linker for the arm target.
ENV PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS=1 
RUN echo '[target.arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf]\nlinker = "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc"' >> /root/.cargo/config

ENV USER=root
RUN cargo new /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN git clone https://github.com/paritytech/parity && cd parity && \
    /root/.cargo/bin/rustup target add arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf && \
    /root/.cargo/bin/cargo build --target=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf --release --features final

# Verify that the output file is for armv6
RUN readelf --arch-specific ./target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/src

RUN file /build/parity/target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/release/parity

EXPOSE 8080 8545 8180
ENTRYPOINT ["/build/parity/target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/release/parity"]
```

The error is:

```
process didn't exit successfully: `/src/parity/target/release/build/backtrace-sys-3c9a41016b6512eb/build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
--- stdout
TARGET = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
HOST = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
CC_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
CC_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
HOST_CC = None
CC = Some("arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc")
CFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
CFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
HOST_CFLAGS = None
CFLAGS = None
DEBUG = Some("false")
running: "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "src/libbacktrace" "-I" "/src/parity/target/release/build/backtrace-sys-5fc2d3da7fb5f8d4/out" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-DBACKTRACE_ELF_SIZE=64" "-DBACKTRACE_SUPPORTED=1" "-DBACKTRACE_USES_MALLOC=1" "-DBACKTRACE_SUPPORTS_THREADS=0" "-DBACKTRACE_SUPPORTS_DATA=0" "-DHAVE_DL_ITERATE_PHDR=1" "-D_GNU_SOURCE=1" "-D_LARGE_FILES=1" "-Dbacktrace_full=__rbt_backtrace_full" "-Dbacktrace_dwarf_add=__rbt_backtrace_dwarf_add" "-Dbacktrace_initialize=__rbt_backtrace_initialize" "-Dbacktrace_pcinfo=__rbt_backtrace_pcinfo" "-Dbacktrace_syminfo=__rbt_backtrace_syminfo" "-Dbacktrace_get_view=__rbt_backtrace_get_view" "-Dbacktrace_release_view=__rbt_backtrace_release_view" "-Dbacktrace_alloc=__rbt_backtrace_alloc" "-Dbacktrace_free=__rbt_backtrace_free" "-Dbacktrace_vector_finish=__rbt_backtrace_vector_finish" "-Dbacktrace_vector_grow=__rbt_backtrace_vector_grow" "-Dbacktrace_vector_release=__rbt_backtrace_vector_release" "-Dbacktrace_close=__rbt_backtrace_close" "-Dbacktrace_open=__rbt_backtrace_open" "-Dbacktrace_print=__rbt_backtrace_print" "-Dbacktrace_simple=__rbt_backtrace_simple" "-Dbacktrace_qsort=__rbt_backtrace_qsort" "-Dbacktrace_create_state=__rbt_backtrace_create_state" "-Dbacktrace_uncompress_zdebug=__rbt_backtrace_uncompress_zdebug" "-o" "/src/parity/target/release/build/backtrace-sys-5fc2d3da7fb5f8d4/out/src/libbacktrace/alloc.o" "-c" "src/libbacktrace/alloc.c"
cargo:warning=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-m64'
exit code: 1
--- stderr
thread 'main
```

I've set my `ENV TARGET=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf` in the Dockerfile, but when the error happens and it complains about not understanding what `-m64` is, it's compiling for a `TARGET = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")`, which is not the target I specified.

How do I make compilation use the original target I specified in the Dockerfile?

[This is the dockerhub build](https://cloud.docker.com/repository/registry-1.docker.io/yazanator90/parity-arm/builds/311a205f-d0e7-495d-976d-e9a929267007)

Answer (score 3):

[`TARGET`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-cargo-reads) isn't used by Cargo. Cargo can be configured by environment variables as follows:

> Cargo can also be configured through environment variables in addition to the TOML syntax above. For each configuration key above of the form `foo.bar` the environment variable `CARGO_FOO_BAR` can also be used to define the value. For example the `build.jobs` key can also be defined by `CARGO_BUILD_JOBS`.

[Source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#environment-variables)

You are confused by an environment variable that Cargo **set** for your build script:

> Cargo sets several environment variables when build scripts are run. Because these variables are not yet set when the build script is compiled, the above example using `env!` won't work and instead you'll need to retrieve the values when the build script is run:
>
> `TARGET` - the target triple that is being compiled for. Native code should be compiled for this triple. Some more information about target triples can be found in clang’s own documentation.

[Source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-cargo-sets-for-build-scripts)

To fix your docker script do:

```
ENV CARGO_BUILD_TARGET=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
```

See:

- [How can I set default build target for Cargo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49453571/how-can-i-set-default-build-target-for-cargo)

Comment: Thanks, will try this now!

Comment: Looks like still showing the same error after adding it to my Dockerfile. I'll try to compile it manually sans Dockerfile in case Docker is doing something weird.

Comment: Didn't work for me in the Dockerfile, but did so without Docker. I believe something in Running it from Docker causes this bug, will try to find a fix.

Comment: @Yazanator sorry I don't use docker so I can't help much about this, if this answer doesn't answer you don't accept it.

Comment: gotcha, I posted a solution I found a few hours back. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I should've been compiling to armhv7 which is compatible with the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B.

This is a Dockerfile that compiles the parity binary for armhv7:

```
FROM debian:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    ca-certificates \
    cmake \
    curl \
    git \
    pkg-config \
    gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf \
    g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf \
    libc6-dev-armhf-cross \
    && rm -rf \
    /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN sed 's/^deb/deb-src/' /etc/apt/sources.list > \
        /etc/apt/sources.list.d/deb-src.list \
    && dpkg --add-architecture armhf \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        libssl-dev:armhf \
        libc6-dev:armhf \
    && rm -rf \
      /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV USER=root
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y --verbose
ENV PATH=/root/.cargo/bin:$PATH

ENV CARGO_TARGET_ARMV7_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNUEABIHF_LINKER=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc \
    CC_armv7_unknown_linux_gnueabihf="/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" \
    CXX_armv7_unknown_linux_gnueabihf="/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++" \
    CROSS_COMPILE="1" \
    OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR="/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf" \
    OPENSSL_LIB_DIR="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf"

RUN /root/.cargo/bin/rustup target add armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf

RUN dpkg --add-architecture armhf && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libudev-dev:armhf

RUN git clone https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum.git && cd parity-ethereum && \
    cargo build --target=armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf --release


CMD ./parity-ethereum/target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/release/parity

EXPOSE 8080 8545 8180
ENTRYPOINT ["/build/parity/target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/release/parity"]
```

Comment: It doesnt work and giving an error... error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'duration_as_u128' (see issue #50202)
  --> ethcore/src/engines/clique/mod.rs:342:75

Comment: any solution for that?